# Texture filtering modes for integer textures

Tags: opengl, textures

why filtering modes including trilinear, bilinear filtering is not allowed for integer textures? Why mipmapping is also not allowed?

Comment: If you're speaking of https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_integer.txt mipmapping should be allowed.

Comment: This is mostly speculation, but bilinear/trilinear filtering on an integer texture would result in a floating point color value, which isn't an integer.

Comment: You can't filter integer textures, that's kind of the point. The same way you cannot blit a depth/stencil buffer using GL_LINEAR, the result of filtering just wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, mipmapping is allowed, the minification filter can be `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST`. I share @ColonelThirtyTwo's speculation. Sampling an integer texture produces integer values, and that wouldn't be the case if you allowed interpolation.